# Write 1 million rows of CSV into S3 by batches

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to build a very large CSV file on S3.

- I want to build this file on S3
- I want to append rows to this file in batches.
- Number of rows could be anywhere between 10k to 1M
- Size of each batch could be < 5Mb(So multi-part upload is not feasible)

What would be the right way of accomplishing something like this?

Comment: How will you be _using_ these CSV files? The creation and content should reflect the usage.

Comment: I need to build the CSV file and send the link to mail. Basically, I'm trying to achieve a retry mechanism. i.e if the build process fails after 500K, I need to resume from that point

Comment: But _WHY_? How is the CSV file going to be _used?_ Does the recipient really one a single, large file? How are they going to consume the information? Would they actually prefer multiple files, or compressed file(s)? Start at the end, then work your way backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally in Big Data processing ("Data Lakes"), information related to a single table are stored in a **directory rather than a single file**. So, appending information to a table is as simple as adding another file to a directory. All files within the directory will need to be the same schema (such as CSV columns, or JSON data).

The directory of files can then be used with tools such as:

- Spark, Hive and Presto on Hadoop
- Amazon Athena
- Amazon Redshift Spectrum

A benefit of this method is that the above systems can **process multiple files in parallel** rather than being restricted to processing a single file in a single-threaded method.

Also common is to **compress the files** using technologies like **gzip**. This lowers storage requirements and makes it faster to read data from disk. Adding additional files is easy (just add another `csv.gz` file) rather than having to unzip, append and re-zip a file.

**Bottom line:** It would be advisable to re-think your requirements for "one great big CSV file".

Answer (score 1):

'One big file' isn't going to work for you - you can't append rows to an s3 file, without first downloading the entire file, adding the rows, and then uploading the new file over the old one - for small files, it will work, but as the file gets larger, the bandwidth and processing is going to go up geometrically on you, and may get very slow and possibly expensive.

Better off refactoring your design to work with lots of little files instead of one big one.

Answer (score 0):

Leave a 5MB garbage object sitting on S3 and do concatenation with it where part 1 = 5MB garbage object, part 2 = your file that you want to upload and concatenate. Keep repeating this for each fragment and finally use the range copy to strip out the 5MB garbage.